# mongodb query field in object that is being edited

Tags: mongodb, meteor, spacebars

How can I query a field in an object? My html retrieves all the objects in array called 'postcards'

```
Meteor.user.profile.postcards [
    {
    _id: 84fh83f,
    field_one: "a name",
    field_two: " winter whether",
    field_three: " lost more writing"
    },
    {
    _id: 6jsf58s,
    field_one: "another  name",
    field_two: " topical issues ",
    field_three: " lost more writing"
    }
   ]
```

Note: I used random.Id() so each object in the array can be uniquely identified.

Setting a session value to `this._id` when the user is focused on the input field will retrieve this unique id, however, I would like to query the actual field in focus.  The value in these fields are projected within the text input area by using the spacebars syntax within the html.

Can I somehow assign the name within the curly braces of the value attribute to a variable? Then query?

Is there a whole new way to achieve this?

**I want to update that specific field in this object instead updating the entire object.**

HTML:

```
{{#with currentUser.profile}}
 {{#each postcards}}
   <input id="one" value="{{field_one}}" type="text">
   <input id="two" value="{{field_two}}" type="text">
   <input id="three" value="{{field_three}}" type="text">
 {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```

client.js

Within events, I would like to update the field on focus upon keyup.

```
Templates.myTemplate.events({
 'keyup input[type=text]': _.throttle(function(event) {
  Meteor.users.update(this._id, {$set: {**fieldbeingedited**: event.target.value}});
  }, 500);
  });
```

Comment: Yes, but the field name is in a variable, it is retrieved from the DOM so am wondering if the specified field can be within a variable for the update operation

Answer (score 0):

What you want to have is an `ES6` capability named 'Computed property names'.

This is what is looks like :

```
var x = 'hello',
    obj = {
      [x]: 'world'
    };
console.log(obj); // Object {hello: "world"}
```

You have two options :
- you use the meteor harmony package to transpile your es6 to es5 (https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-harmony)
- you build your object first

To build you object first :

```
var obj = {};
obj[ this.targetField ] = event.target.value
Meteor.users.update(this._id, {$set: obj});
```

Comment: One simple solution I found is setting the data-name to the value of the field being retrieved and then then getting this value by $(event.target).attr("data-name");  

Then storing this value in a variable and used within the query. This meteor-harmony package you mention has capabilities beyond the basic needs of the question. But thank you for making me aware of it.

Comment: Back to the drawing board. I can get the field name position from the data-name but invoking the update is yet to be achieved.