# How to update objects in an array when target field name is in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor, spacebars

I am really struggling to find a way to structure the data that will allow updates that is light on the server.

On the UI, a user clicks add that inserts an object with no values.

```
Meteor.methods({
addExp: function() {
    var expDoc = {
        objId: new Mongo.ObjectID,
        field_one: " ",
        field_two: " ",
        field_three: " "
    };
     var newExpId = Meteor.users.update({_id:this.userId}, {$addToSet: {'profile.experiences': expDoc}});
     return newExpId;
}
});
```

Now, using the spacebars #each block helper in the template, the input fields appear and their value attribute is assigned to these fields.

```
{{#with currentUser.profile}}
    {{#each postcards}}
        <input data-name="field_one" id="one" value="{{field_one}}" type="text">
        <input data-name="field_two" id="two" value="{{field_two}}" type="text">
        <input data-name="field_three" id="three" value="{{field_three}}" type="text">
    {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```

What I am struggling to do is send an update on keyup to the specific field. As the user may add more postcards to this array, I dont know how to target the specific field to update.

On click event, I can get the target field I want because I put this data in the data-name attribute within the input element `var specificField = $(event.target).attr("data-name");`

I was given a solution yesterday [mongodb query field in object that is being edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27485228/mongodb-query-field-in-object-that-is-being-edited) but can not get this to work.

Is there another way for me to structure the data that makes updates easier? The update functionality will be like `meteor create --example todos` but they have one document and one field, so this is easy. But I need more fields other than the 'text' field?

[image]

Ultimately, I am trying to get a user to insert into a form with three input elements. Each element projects the current data of the particular field of that particular object.

Comment: Arrays that are not on the first level of a collection are hard to update. What I have been doing is using two different collections and linking them by their unique id's. So that you would have the `Users` collection and an `Experiences` collection where your `profile` array is full of the unique id's of the the specific `Experiences`.

Comment: So denormalising the data. Each document will still have the three fields in the new collection. How can each field be target to update instead of updating of using $set which overwrites everything?

Comment: Updating part of the document seen possible: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/#specify-an-upsert-true-for-the-update-specific-fields-operation I guess you can use dot notation to specify the field http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set

Comment: The field to update is determined upon which input element is on focus. So this data as far as I can see can only be stored in a variable to perform this operation.

Comment: Just to understand you are trying to keep the old context, but also know which the current context is?

Comment: So the current context is on display, and when the user types there is an update to save this context.

Comment: I was thinking, if I created a Postcard collection with these specific fields. I can then create events specific to the input id. So on focus, the method is called and the only variable I need to pass is the document id as I will have predefined the field that needs to be updated? No more need for field variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Successful operation! Solution: store the field name and value as an object!
I stored the data inside a Profiles collection and managed the update on keyup for specific fields to that particular object.

I stored the field name in an object. 
The value of the input/textarea in focus is stored in a variable. 
The Session stores the id of the doc when the user focuses on the input/textarea field.

HTML:

```
{{#each experiences}} // helper to retrieve the docs from Collection
<input data-name="field_one" id="one" value="{{field_one}}" type="text">
<input data-name="field_two" id="two" value="{{field_two}}" type="text">
{{/each}}
```

client.js

```
'focus input[type=text], focus textarea[type=text]': function(event) {
 Session.set('DOCID', this._id);
```

This is the event that calls the update method every 5 seconds on keyup.

```
  'keyup input[type=text], keyup textarea[type=text]': _.throttle(function(event) {
    var data = event.target.value;
    var specificField = $(event.target).attr("data-name");
    var keyVal = {};
    keyVal[specificField] = data;
    var docId = Session.get('DOCID');
    Meteor.call('updateExp', docId, keyVal);
  }, 5000),
```

the method:
server.js

```
  updateExp: function(docId, keyVal) {
    Experiences.update({_id: docId}, {$set: keyVal});
  }
```

If you decide to store the objects within an array, the following is how you do it. 
Example: storing the objects inside of an array called 'experiences' in 
Meteor.user().profile.experiences.

HTML:

```
{{#with currentUser.profile}}
{{#each postcards}}
<input data-name="profile.experiences.$.field_one" id="one" value="{{field_one}}" type="text">
<input data-name="profile.experiences.$.field_two" id="two" value="{{field_two}}" type="text">
{{/each}}
{{/with}}
// notice the path and positional operator within the data-name. The positional $ operator 
//will act as a placeholder for the first element (our objId) that matches the query document. The event handler will store the data-name into an object for the update operation.
```

client.js

```
'focus input[type=text], focus textarea[type=text]': function(event) {
 Session.set('DOCID', this.objId); 
}
```

`objId` is the field where the Mongo.ObjectID() is stored. (ref code in question)

The keyup event handler remains the same.

However, the method is different.

server.js

```
updateExp: function(docId, keyVal) {
Meteor.users.update({_id: this.userId, 'profile.experiences.docId': docId }, {$set: keyVal});
}
```